# Running maven project via apache-maven server

Tags: java, apache, maven

Dear all I have a maven project and I need to run it using apache-maven I'm using the command `mvn install` to compile and add it to `.m2 repository` but how can I run this maven project via `apache-maven server` without using IDE's 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow these steps to find the solution of the main question:
https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a simple Java project, you have to identify the Main class. If you are using Maven for the build, the packaging will have to specify which class contains the main method.

You can do the above in Maven POM by adding a manifest in the configuration for the maven-jar-plugin which is responsible for the packaging. In other words, you simply add the following to your POM.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>
                    org.baeldung.executable.ExecutableMavenJar
                    <!--Full classified name of the class that contains the main method -->
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once the JAR is created, you can execute it by invoking the following:
    java -jar jarName.jar

You can find more details on the topic at http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: But my case i'm developing a plugin into a web application; this plugin is installed by adding a url into installation url field that's called a json file this json file will call a java servlets, and the plugin should be in form of war file that needs a apache maven server to run this war file and be ready to respond to the requests

Comment: For running a Servlet based application, you'll have to use a servlet container, right? You can either use an external servlet container like Apache Tomcat or you can package a servlet container with your application. Maven alone will not be of much help!